# does user.dmp contain only the most recent crash

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, windbg, drwatson, dr.watson

I wanted to know if the "user.dmp" created by drwtsn32 has only the most recent crash.
I tried to capture a few crashes. But when i tried to analyse it, I just see one crash.

Thanks for the help,
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one crash dump, although the log file may contain information on previous crashes.
Run drwtsn32.exe (without any arguments) to bring up the configuration dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  I recommend setting WinDbg as the default post-mortem debugger.  You can save your dumps from there.

Comment: thanks robert. What I wanted to know was, does the dump have only the most recent crash. Or can I use the dump to analyze the previous 4-5 crashes.? 
thanks again

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, the dump does only have the most recent crash.